# how to include aar files dependency in proguard?

Tags: android, odata, proguard

I have some aar and jar files in my project for odata web service and image scanning purpose. While enabling proguard for dependencies i din't get any warning for these libs but app is not working. may i know how to write proguard rules to keep these libs?

```
implementation(name: 'OData/xxx-2.2.2', ext: 'aar')
implementation files('libs/OData/xxx-2.2.2.2.jar')
```

Comment: @SumitShukla i'm looking for proguard for included aar files. R8 is something new which doesn't support aar files it looks. Thanks.

Comment: i can see it as "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeHandle" in class "Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;". This is denoting to an aar file.Issue is i couldnt find a way to keep this file in proguard rules. any idea about how to add aar files in proguard?